# Are the brackets used correctly in the equation in java?

Tags: java

```
double y = [(100-totalGrade)*weightCategory]+(totalGrade*x);
```

is this a valid equation? Mainly wondering if the brackets are used correctly

Comment: And this is called `Bracket Over(loading|using)`.

Answer (score 4):

No, the brackets are not used correctly. the square brackets (`[` `]`) are reserved for accessing array elements.

You want to use nested parenthesis: 
`double y = ((100-totalGrade)*weightCategory)+(totalGrade*x);`

but in your equation, as alex pointed out:

`double y = (100-totalGrade)*weightCategory+totalGrade*x;`

is sufficient.

Comment: @ShayanShaikh If you like this answer, feel free to set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is enough:

`double y = (100-totalGrade)*weightCategory+totalGrade*x;`

Answer (score 1):

`[` and `]` are not accepted in Java as the brackets you see in math, they are used to declare arrays. You must use `(` and `)` in their places.

Comment: Saying they're "not accepted" a bit confusing, since `[` and `]` are valid operators in Java, albeit for arrays rather than for nested parentheses.

Comment: I assumed we are in the context of mathematical operation, but you have a good point, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you need nested brackets you just continue to use `(` and `)`, ensuring that you close each pair properly.

The `[` and `]` characters are used for subscript operators, such as in arrays, e.g. the parameter for a main method `String[] args`.

If you follow the rules of BIDMAS/BODMAS, you'll see that you don't in fact need your outer brackets in your case. However, should you need them in future, use nested parentheses like so:

`int example = (1+2)*((3+4)*5);`